# Help with making a seperate gallery for multiple links on same page in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I am trying to make a gallery of images open from a link in a lightbox, I have the basics down, and I have one link that opens a gallery of images, but I have 6 different links on the page that I want to open a different gallery of images for each one, when I set it up it does not display the gallery, only one image.  Is there a way to duplicate this:

HTML

```
 <div id='gallery'>
        <a href="images/big-image1.jpg">
            <img src="images/thumbnail-image1.jpg"/>
        </a>
        <a href="images/big-image2.jpg" ></a>
        <a href="images/big-image3.jpg" ></a>
        <a href="images/big-image4.jpg" ></a>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox();
});
```

for each set-up, and have them work?  Do I need to assign them different div names to make them work?

Thanks, Jessica

Comment: Hi, what you are asking isn't that clear to me. Do you want the links inside '#gallery' to open different galleries? Where are they getting the list of images for the gallery? Or do you have 6 different divs and each should open a new gallery?

Comment: I have 6 different divs that should open a new gallery for each, I took out the thumbnail and added a text link to activate the lightbox. The example above is what I found in this forum that worked for me, but only for one div, and 5 images, when I try to duplicate it to the next div, it only displays the first image and nothing else....does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you have six different divs, you'll have to call the jQuery Lightbox plugin six times:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#gallery1 a').lightBox();
  $('#gallery2 a').lightBox();
  $('#gallery3 a').lightBox();
  $('#gallery4 a').lightBox();
  $('#gallery5 a').lightBox();
  $('#gallery6 a').lightBox();
});
```

Another option would be to just have one div and each image have a rel tag attribute to group them into galleries:

HTML

```
<div id="gallery">

 <!-- gallery 1 -->
 <a href="full-image-1.jpg" rel="group1"><img src="thumb-1.jpg"></a>
 <a href="full-image-2.jpg" rel="group1"><img src="thumb-2.jpg"></a>
 <a href="full-image-3.jpg" rel="group1"><img src="thumb-3.jpg"></a>

 <!-- gallery 2 -->
 <a href="full-image-4.jpg" rel="group2"><img src="thumb-4.jpg"></a>
 <a href="full-image-5.jpg" rel="group2"><img src="thumb-5.jpg"></a>
 <a href="full-image-6.jpg" rel="group2"><img src="thumb-6.jpg"></a>

 <!-- gallery 3 -->
 <a href="full-image-7.jpg" rel="group3"><img src="thumb-7.jpg"></a>
 <a href="full-image-8.jpg" rel="group3"><img src="thumb-8.jpg"></a>
 <a href="full-image-9.jpg" rel="group3"><img src="thumb-9.jpg"></a>

 <!-- etc -->

</div>
```

then use this script (you'll still have to run it six times):

```
$("#gallery a[rel=group1]").lightBox();
$("#gallery a[rel=group2]").lightBox();
$("#gallery a[rel=group3]").lightBox();
// etc
```